# How to encrypt vector tiles JSON response

Tags: encryption, geojson, tilestache, vector-tiles

I am using TileStache to serve vector tiles from PostgreSQL and using Tangram to display these tiles by passing URL ('http://localhost:8080/composite/{z}/{x}/{y}.json') in the data source. The response i get is in JSON format, which is what i wanted.

How to encrypt the JSON response? so that it is not human readable at the client end and readable at server end.

Comment: You can only obfuscate, because the client needs the data in order to show the tiles. Are you trying to protect your tiles from stealing by the client?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what i am trying to do... i don't want the client to download and steal my data

Answer (score 2):

You can use [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for encoding the data. Here are two implementations [geobuf](https://github.com/mapbox/geobuf) and [vt-pbf](https://github.com/anandthakker/vt-pbf). But stealing of data can not be stopped as it need to be decoded at client side.

Comment: You are right, converting json into pbf format can solve my issue up to some extent. Thank you, I am looking into [geobuf](https://github.com/mapbox/geobuf).

Comment: Just go through this [twkb](https://github.com/TWKB/twkb.js) also, one more lib for same purpose.